How to Enable Validity VFS495 Fingerprint Reader on HP ProBook 450 G4 with Ubuntu 24.04.1
I have an HP ProBook 450 G4 laptop with a Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader (ID 138a:003f), and I am using Ubuntu 24.04. I want to enable fingerprint security on my laptop, but I'm unsure if this specific fingerprint reader is supported on Ubuntu 24.04.1.
What I've Tried So Far:
Installed fprintd and libfprint using.
Checked if the device is detected using lsusb, and it shows up as Validity Sensors, Inc.
Attempted to register my fingerprint with fprintd-enroll, but it doesn't seem to recognize the device or complete the process successfully.
My Questions:

Is the VFS495 fingerprint reader fully supported on Ubuntu 24.04.1?
Are there any specific drivers or additional steps I need to follow
to make it work?
Has anyone successfully set up this fingerprint
reader on Ubuntu, and if so, how?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, suggestions, or workarounds to get the fingerprint reader working on my device. Thank you!
